# JdbcTemplate query in Oracle matching against fixed-character field

Tags: java, oracle, spring-data

I'm trying to write some code which given a list of IDs fetches matching records from a DB. This should be pretty straightforward. However, the ID field is of type CHAR(20). This seems like a case that spring-data doesn't handle properly so my queries (while functional) do not return any records. This is against a vendor product's DB so the changes I can make to the schema are limited.

```
create table items (
      item_id char(20)
)

insert into items (item_id) values ('12345');
```

and the following application code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyWorker {
      @Autowired
      private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate myDb;

      private static final String query = "select item_id\n" + 
            "from items\n" +
            "where item_id in (:item_ids)";

      public void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MyWorker.class);
            app.setWebEnvironment(false);
            app.run(args);
      }

      public void run(String ... args) {
            String[] lookupIds = new String[] { "12345" };
            MapSqlParameterSource paramMap = new MapSqlParameterSource();
            paramMap.addValue("item_ids", Arrays.asList(lookupIds), java.sql.Types.CHAR);

            System.out.println("Starting.");
            myDb.query(QueryConfiguration.skuQueryStockedById, paramMap ,
            r -> { 
                  System.out.println("Read " + r.getString(1));
            });
            System.out.println("Done.");
      }
}
```

I can adjust the query above as follows and get this to work, at the cost of seriously degraded performance since this ignores any indexes.

```
select item_id
from items
where rtrim(item_id) in (:item_ids)
```

Are there any other solutions I should consider? I assume I could use JDBC natively but before I rewrite a lot of code I wanted to see if there are better alternatives. Looking each record up individually is probably not viable as I'm expecting to process thousands of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the simplest solution is just to pad the values in the code:

```
    String[] lookupIds = new String[] { "12345" };
    MapSqlParameterSource paramMap = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    List<String> paddedIds = Arrays.asList(lookupIds).stream()
        .map(i -> { return String.format("%1$-40s",i); })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    paramMap.addValue("item_ids", paddedIds, java.sql.Types.CHAR);
```